# Vector normal to parametrized circle

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Suppose there is a circle given by equation c: $(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2=4$ and and another identical circle given by the parametric equation $$\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}3\\2\end{array}\right)+2\left(\begin{array}{c}cos\theta\\sin\theta\end{array}\right)\quad0\le\theta\le2\pi$$So we are given point $A$ on the circle. The norm for point A, using the Cartesian equation is $$\nabla c=\left(\begin{array}{c}2x-6\\2y-4\end{array}\right)$$ So at point $A$, a line orthogonal to the circle can be written as $(x,y)=A+t\cdot\nabla c\quad-\infty\le t\le\infty.$ I would like to know how to write the vector normal, $\mathbf{u}$, to the parametrized circle equation so that I could obtain a similar (as in identical) orthogonal line at $A$.  What seems obvious is to use $\mathbf{u}=(dx/d\theta, dy/d\theta) = (-2sin\theta,\,2cos\theta)$, but if I let $A=(5,2)$  which is just a point on the circle 2 units to the right center, then $\nabla c = (4,0)$, but since $\theta = 0$, $\mathbf{u} = (0,2)$. Where have I gone wrong?  I would like to be able to apply this to a 3d parametric circle.  Thought I should understand the 2d case first.

Comment: what seems obvious might not be the case... note that $\nabla c = (\partial_{x} c \, \partial_{y}c)^{T}$ which is not the same with the one you used above.

Comment: @amd I corrected $\nabla c$. I am still looking at your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fundamental error here is that $\mathbf u'$ is *tangent* to the curve, not normal to it. Once you’ve corrected that, you will still find that the gradient of $c$ is not equal to the normal (not “norm”) computed from the parameterization $\mathbf u(\theta)$, but this is to be expected—there’s no such thing as *the* normal to the curve. The vectors will be scalar multiples of each other, but there’s no guarantee that they’ll be equal. Indeed, you could just as well parameterize the circle as $(3+\cos\theta, 2-\sin\theta)$ or $(3+\cos2\theta,2+\sin2\theta)$, both of which will produce different tangent vectors.

Comment: I suppose this means that the normal to a 3d parametric circle will come from the gradient to the sphere equation written in $x,y,z$.  Given that $\mathbf{u \prime}$  is tangent to the curve, I may be able to use that to get an general orthogonal vector for any $\theta$.

Comment: @Narlin In 3D you have to be a bit more precise about *which* normal you want since there’s an entire plane perpendicular to any tangent vector. The circle is a plane curve, though, so you can get a normal in the circle’s plane by computing the cross product of a tangent to the circle and normal to that plane. This will be a scalar multiple of the standard [unit normal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html) from differential geometry that’s defined by the [Frenet-Serret formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas).